# Querying fusion tables through HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, user-interface

I am trying to carry out a query using a html form but seem to be encountering an error

Here is my code...

Firstly I have a basic html form :

```
<form action="fusion.html" method="get">
<select name="Country" onchange= "showCountry(this)">
        <option value="GREECE">Greece</option>
        <option value="INDONESIA">Indonesia</option>
        <option value="INDIA">India</option>
        <option value="BULGARIA">Bulgaria</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</html>
```

and a fusion.html form :

```
<title>Sample form</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load("current", { packages: ['table'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(loadDefault);
function showCountry(event) {
google.visualization.drawChart({
  "containerId": "visualization_div",
  "dataSourceUrl": "//www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=",
  "query": "SELECT 'COUNTRY', 'YEAR', 'DEATHS'FROM " +
           "12V3p4kEXoqyEZATix74oFw6-qxgotbwovFAoHi2g WHERE 'COUNTRY'= '" 
           + event.value + "'",
  "chartType": "Table",
  "options": {}
});
}

function loadDefault() {
  showCountry({value: "GREECE"});
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
<div id="visualization_div" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>
```

When I run this , no matter what the user selects in the drop down box on the form , it prints out GREECE. Any one have any idea how to get it to print out what the user is selecting ?

Comment: Try `function showCountry(cty)` and ` + cty + "'"`

Comment: where abouts do I put the           ` + cty + "'"`             bit ?

Comment: Last part of query

Comment: Sorry also `onchange="showCountry(this.value)"`

Comment: Im a bit confused , could you fill it into my code i put above to show me ?

Comment: Sure, but it won't function since SO is sandboxed.

Comment: Even just the line you are changing. Just trying to see how exactly i edit

Comment: Ok, it works take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess what? It works great, it doesn't need to be submitted so I removed the submit button. Perhaps you didn't load jQuery or perhaps you placed the script elsewhere?

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sample form</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load("current", {
      packages: ['table']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(loadDefault);

    function show(event) {
      google.visualization.drawChart({
        "containerId": "visualization_div",
        "dataSourceUrl": "//www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=",
        "query": "SELECT 'COUNTRY', 'YEAR', 'DEATHS', 'INJURIES' FROM " +
          "12V3p4kEXoqyEZATix74oFw6-qxgotbwovFAoHi2g WHERE 'COUNTRY'= '" + event.value + "'",
        "chartType": "Table",
        "options": {}
      });
    }

    function loadDefault() {
      show({
        value: "GREECE",
        value: "DEATHS"
      });
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
  <form action="fusion.html" method="get">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Country</legend>
      <select id='country' name="country" onchange="show(this)">
        <option value="GREECE">Greece</option>
        <option value="INDONESIA">Indonesia</option>
        <option value="INDIA">India</option>
        <option value="BULGARIA">Bulgaria</option>
      </select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id='casualty'>
      <legend>Casualty Count</legend>
    <label>Deaths<input class='chx' id='death' name='death' type='checkbox' value='DEATH' onchange='show(this)' checked></label>
    <label>Injuries<input class='chx'id='injury' name='injury' type='checkbox' value='INJURY' onchange='show(this)' checked></label>
      </fieldset>
  </form>
  <div id="visualization_div" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for that really appreciate it. Do You know if it is possible to include a submit button , basically using 2 seperate files , one directing to the other ?

Comment: also what would i add to that code to add more than one input from the user ?

Comment: Try changing the onchange into onsubmit. If this post has resolved your issue go ahead and click the green ✔.

Comment: More than one input = more than one chart or chart with each country?

Comment: when i do that i get the same just the default. More than one i mean that i have more than one variable which goes into the query

Comment: Try `method="post">` on form. It depends on what the variables are, you would need to change the function's parameters accordingly and moreso if these variables are optional.

Comment: Back to the two page matter...you need those 2 pages "talking" to each other, so a hidden iframe is one way or ajax would be an option.

Comment: think ill leave the submit button. Last question , if i added another form which say got the user to select between Death and Injury and I wanted my query to read in the country chosen and either death and injury and do this query : "SELECT 'COUNTRY', 'YEAR', WHERE 'COUNTRY' = *user input* and *death or injury* < 10 . What would I need to change to do that

Comment: Is injury another table or is it a column on the same table as death?

Comment: Injuries and Death are both columns in the one table

Comment: I have updated it so there's a checkbox for both DEATHS and INJURIES. The query is modified to show both, but the checkboxes do not function. All you'll need to do is find the right syntax to modify the query. If you want, you can give me your email (if you are paranoid like me, just make a new throwaway account), and I'll send you an ebook on  GViz. Although it's a little outdated, there is a whole chapter on FusionTables and how to use the query language.

Comment: Instead of that , If i wanted to run 2 seperate queries on the same page , how do i break that down ? When i do , the second input updates the first page.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'd say 2 separate tables, or DataView class